# JPA createQuery()

Tags: jpa

When using JPA createQuery(), I found that we can use both class name and entity name to get the DB data.

This is by class name

> em.createQuery("from com.model.Stuff s", 
>       Stuff.class).getResultList();

And this is from entity name

> em.createQuery("from Stuff s", 
>       Stuff.class).getResultList();

This is in orm.xml

```
<entity class="com.model.Stuff" name="Stuff">
```

No matter which one i use, JPA can get the specific class that i am using from the orm.xml or from the annotation that i put in class.

1. So why i have to put Stuff.class in the parameter?
2. Because it can only put at most two parameters in createQuery(), What if i have to select two Class to do some join?

   i cannot do this

   > em.createQuery("from Stuff s, Thing t where s.id = t.stuff_id",  Stuff.class, Thing.class).getResultList();
3. Is

   > em.createQuery("from Stuff s", 
   >       Stuff.class).getResultList();

   equal

   > em.createQuery("select s from Stuff s", 
   >       Stuff.class).getResultList();

Thanks to give me some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Stuff.class` goes into the parameter to determine what type of query result object. A query can be infinitely complicated with dozens of nested types, but it must return one type of object in the end.
2. Then you must create a third Java type that will be result of join. Think about it, what type SHOULD the result be after a join?
3. As far as I know, yes